# GRE verbal: Score per Question

Tags: gre

Is there any exact or approximate measure for the score of each question in GRE verbal?

Can I estimate my verbal score for answering n questions correctly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. The GRE is an adaptive exam. Different test-takers are given a second section of varying difficulty, depending on how well they scored in the first section. If you get a section with more difficult questions, they will be scaled differently than if you would have answered easy questions.

The number of questions you answer correctly on the Verbal and Quantitative sections become your "raw score" for each section. Then,

> The raw score is converted to a scaled score through a process known as equating. The equating process accounts for minor variations in difficulty among the different test editions as well as the differences in difficulty introduced by the section-level adaptation. Thus a given scaled score for a particular measure reflects the same level of performance regardless of which second section was selected and when the test was taken.

You have no way of knowing how your scaled score will be computed based only the number of questions you answered correctly, because it also depends on the difficulty of the section you took.

(Reference: [How the Test Is Scored, ETS](https://www.ets.org/gre/revised_general/scores/how/))